# How do I fill a large array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, kill-process

I'm trying to fill an array of size 2 ^ 32 and at a certain stage of filling it gives out that the process was killed

```
def MakeArr(n):
    start_time = time.time()

    arr = np.random.randint(1, 2**n, size=2**n, dtype=np.int64)

    print(arr)
    print("Time to create: %s sec" % (time.time() - start_time))
    print("arr len:" + str(len(arr)))
    return arr
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500); n = 32; arr = MakeArr(n)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpt9m.png)

Comment: Do you have the 16gb of memory you need to allocate this array?

Comment: open the task manager and watch your ram usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of 2^32 may be too large for python or numpy to handle. You may be able to get a bigger array by changing the dtype to a lower one, like `np.int8`.

Comment: This works, but is there a way to increase the range of random numbers?

Comment: There's a tradeoff between how large your array is and how large your numbers can be. You're limited by the amount of memory you have

Comment: Now I understand, thanks

Comment: You could get probably get some more value by using a NumPy uint. They don't allow for negative numbers but the range is thus twice as good

Comment: Got it, I'll try